# facebook integration with asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication, registration

I have implemented a Facebook login and registration into an ASP.NET website I am working on but not sure if I have the best process. **Any comments/corrections welcome.** I found the development process a bit disjointed... facebook gives you pieces of the puzzle but falls short on how the pieces fit together in my view. Here's how I did it:-

MASTER PAGE:-

```
<!doctype html>
<%--facebook namespace needed for xfbml ...--%>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

script to include facebook sdk and facebook login javascript function which posts back to the ASP.NET app to check the facebook email against the user table in our database. As you can see the facebook UserID is commented out as I did not manage to extract it with the notation used. (Any ideas on how to do this?) :-

```
<%--the fb-root div is used by the facebook sdk and the like plugin further below the sdk load --%>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<%--facebook javascript SDK--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));

      // Init the SDK upon load
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
          channelUrl : '//'+window.location.hostname+'/channel.htm', // Path to your Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
      } 

      // catch Facebook login button press
      function FacebookLogin() {

        // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {

            // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
            // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
            form.setAttribute("action", '/RegistrationFacebookTestForUser.aspx');

//          var field = document.createElement("input");
//          field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
//          field.setAttribute("name", 'fbuserid');
//          field.setAttribute("value", response.authResponse.userID);
//          form.appendChild(field);

            var field2 = document.createElement("input");
            field2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            field2.setAttribute("name", 'tempform_email');
            field2.setAttribute("value", response.email.toString());
            form.appendChild(field2);

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        });
      }

</script>
```

The form posts back to RegistrationFacebookTestForUser.aspx.cs to check the users facebook email against our database :-

```
public partial class RegistrationFacebookTestForUser : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //fbid.Text = Request.Form["fbuserid"];
        email.Text = Request.Form["tempform_email"];

        // get user from facebook email
        MembershipUser tempUser = Membership.GetUser(Request.Form["tempform_email"]);

        if (tempUser == null) // if user not found redirect to Facebook Registration Page
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/RegistrationFacebook.aspx");
        }
        else // if user found set auth cookie and redirect
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tempUser.UserName, true);
            Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

If the email is not found redirect to RegistrationFacebook.aspx to offer registration via Facebook registration plugin....

RegistrationFacebook.aspx:-

```
<div id="facebook_registration" runat="server">

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
client_id=110835352327502&
redirect_uri=http://localhost/RegistrationFacebookBackend.aspx&
fields=
[
{'name':'name'},
{'name':'first_name'},
{'name':'last_name'},
{'name':'email'},
{'name':'password'},
{'name':'_business', 'description':'Do you work for ?', 'type':'select', 'options':{'':'I do not work for ','f5f064ad-0db4-42ce-ba86-e65e6d262768':'xxxxxxxx','534d6c7b-6c3a-4b7d-a41c-9e240c199f1d':'xxxxxxxx'}}, 
{'name':'network', 'description':'Please select your region', 'type':'select', 'options':{'a':'a','b':'b','c':'c','d':'d','e':'e','f':'f','g':'g','h':'h','i':'i','j':'j','k':'k','l':'l','96e9b78a-cc3b-4c6e-b4e4-bc0ba18184c1':'UK','521199a2-5847-4ec0-bca1-19052a110da8':'South Africa'}},
{'name':'public_profile',  'description':'Make my profile public so other users can see me', 'type':'checkbox', 'default':'checked'},
{'name':'newsletter',  'description':'Please send me the monthly  Unite newsletter', 'type':'checkbox'},
{'name':'sponsor_email',  'description':'Please email me when someone sponsors me', 'type':'checkbox', 'default':'checked'},
{'name':'tandc',  'description':'I confirm that I have read and accepted the Terms and Conditions', 'type':'checkbox'}
]
"
scrolling="auto"
frameborder="no"
style="border:none"
allowTransparency="true"
width="100%"
height="530">
</iframe>

</div>
```

RegistrationFacebook.aspx.cs :-

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // its a save of content in admin mode
        }
        else 
        {
            // RegistrationFacebookBackend has redirected back here after creating the user
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["facebook_result"]))
            {
                switch (Request.QueryString["facebook_result"])
                {
                    case "Success":
                        CreateAccountResultsSuccess.Text = "You have successfully registered with  Unite and the  Unite Facebook app!";
                        CreateAccountResultsSuccess.Visible = true;
                        facebook_registration.Visible = false;
                        break;
                    case "InvalidUserName":
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Text = Resources.Error_Registration_InvalidUserName;
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case "DuplicateUserName":
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Text = Resources.Error_Registration_DuplicateUserName;
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case "DuplicateEmail":
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Text = Resources.Error_Registration_DuplicateEmail;
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case "InvalidEmail":
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Text = Resources.Error_Registration_InvalidEmail;
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case "InvalidPassword":
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Text = Resources.Error_Registration_InvalidPassword;
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Visible = true;
                        CreateAccountResultsError.Text = Resources.Error_Registration_Default;
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The registration plugin in RegistrationFacebook.aspx posts back to RegistrationFacebookBackend.aspx to register the user with the ASP.NET app. Main things to focus on here are the facebook form signed_request variable decoding in Page_Load and the Membership and profile creation. We use a CachedMembershipProvider but just substitute in normal membership provider code here. (The networkGUID is just part of our app so ignore it :-

```
public partial class RegistrationFacebookBackend : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private UserService userService;
    private MembershipUser newUser;
    private string userName; private string email; private string password; private string firstname; private string lastname;
    private string _business; private string network; private string location;
    private bool newsletter; private bool sponsor_email;
    //private Guid networkId;

    #region public properties

    public UserService UserService
    {
        get { return userService ?? (userService = new UserService()); }
    }

    public MembershipUser NewUser
    {
        get { return newUser ?? (newUser = Membership.GetUser(userName)); }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Load event of the Page control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // 
        }
        else  // Request with Facebook signed_request payload ... create the user
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["signed_request"]))
            {
                string payload = Request.Form["signed_request"].Split('.')[1];
                var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                var decodedJson = payload.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
                var base64JsonArray = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedJson.PadRight(decodedJson.Length + (4 - decodedJson.Length % 4) % 4, '='));
                var json = encoding.GetString(base64JsonArray);

                var o = JObject.Parse(json);

                userName = o.SelectToken("registration.email").ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                email = o.SelectToken("registration.email").ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                password = o.SelectToken("registration.password").ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                firstname = o.SelectToken("registration.first_name").ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                lastname = o.SelectToken("registration.last_name").ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                _business = o.SelectToken("registration._business").ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                network = o.SelectToken("registration.network").ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                location = o.SelectToken("user.country").ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                newsletter = (o.SelectToken("registration.newsletter").ToString().Replace("\"","") == "checked") ? true : false;
                sponsor_email = (o.SelectToken("registration.sponsor_email").ToString().Replace("\"","") == "checked") ? true : false;


                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                CachedMembershipProvider cmp = new CachedMembershipProvider();
                System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
                nvc.Add("providerName","AspNetSqlMembershipProvider");
                cmp.Initialize("CachedMembershipProvider", nvc );
                newUser = cmp.CreateUser(userName, password, email, null, null, true, Guid.NewGuid(), out createStatus);
                switch (createStatus)
                {
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.Success:
                        // set roles and create profile
                        SetUserProfile(true);
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newUser.UserName, true);
                        Response.Redirect("RegistrationFacebook.aspx?facebook_result=Success");
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
                        Response.Redirect("RegistrationFacebook.aspx?facebook_result=InvalidUserName");
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                        Response.Redirect("RegistrationFacebook.aspx?facebook_result=DuplicateUserName");
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                        Response.Redirect("RegistrationFacebook.aspx?facebook_result=DuplicateEmail");
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                        Response.Redirect("RegistrationFacebook.aspx?facebook_result=InvalidEmail");
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                        Response.Redirect("RegistrationFacebook.aspx?facebook_result=InvalidPassword");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Response.Redirect("RegistrationFacebook.aspx?facebook_result=error_default");
                        break;
                }


            }
            else  // Request WITHOUT Facebook signed_request payload
            {

            }


        }

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the user profile.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="profileUserName">Name of the user.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Web.WebProfile GetUserProfile(string profileUserName)
    {
        ProfileBase wp = Web.WebProfile.Create(profileUserName);
        return new Web.WebProfile(wp);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the user profile.
    /// </summary>
    private void SetUserProfile(bool createEvents)
    {
        if (newUser == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("newUser");
        }

        //Control container = CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer;

        Web.WebProfile newProfile = GetUserProfile(NewUser.UserName);
        newProfile.UserId = (Guid)NewUser.ProviderUserKey;
        newProfile.FirstName = firstname;
        newProfile.LastName = lastname;
        newProfile.EmailAddress = email;
        newProfile.NetworkId = NetworkGuid;
        newProfile.FurtherInformationOptIn = true;
        newProfile.Location = location;
        newProfile.IsTemporary = false;
        newProfile.OptInFavourites = false;
        newProfile.OptInNewsletters = newsletter;
        newProfile.OptInGiveTimeEvents = false;
        newProfile.OptInFundraisers = sponsor_email;
        newProfile.OptInNews = false;
        newProfile.Save();
        newProfile = new WebProfile(WebProfile.Create(NewUser.UserName));
        UserService.CreateNewProfilePage(newProfile, false);
        if (createEvents)
        {
            EventService ues = new EventService();
            IEvent ue = ues.CreateEvent(EventType.Registration, newProfile.NetworkId, newProfile.UserId,
                                        newProfile.UserId);
        }
    }


    protected Guid NetworkGuid
    {
        get
        {
            Guid networkGuid;

            if (Convertors.GuidTryParse(_business, out networkGuid) == true)
            {
                return networkGuid; // if they have selected a business that is the one to use
            }
            else if (Convertors.GuidTryParse(network, out networkGuid) == true)
            {
                return networkGuid; // otherwise use the region they have selected
            }
            else
            {   //otherwise default to UK
                Convertors.GuidTryParse("96e9b78a-cc3b-4c6e-b4e4-bc0ba18184c1", out networkGuid);
                return networkGuid;
            }


        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Thanks for an idea of embedding the FB in site; Were you were satisfied with this approach?